# libcurl - CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION (HTTP2 without TLS)

Tags: c

**libcurl** has option CURLOPT_HTTP_*VERSION* with next parameters:

CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS:

> Attempt HTTP 2 **over TLS** (HTTPS) only.

CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE:

> Issue **non-TLS** HTTP requests using HTTP/2

Doesn 't http 2 work automatically with a TLS Connection ?
Can http 2 be with an open non - encrypted connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, HTTP/2 [can work without encryption](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption). But most of implementations supports only encrypted requests. As of mentioned parameters they are described in documentation:

> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS
>
> Attempt HTTP 2 over TLS (HTTPS) only. libcurl will fall back to HTTP
> 1.1 if HTTP 2 cannot be negotiated with the HTTPS server. For clear text HTTP servers, libcurl will use 1.1. (Added in 7.47.0)
>
> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE
>
> Issue non-TLS HTTP requests using HTTP/2 without HTTP/1.1 Upgrade. It
> requires prior knowledge that the server supports HTTP/2 straight
> away. HTTPS requests will still do HTTP/2 the standard way with
> negotiated protocol version in the TLS handshake. (Added in 7.49.0)

So CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS has fallback to HTTP 1.1 protocol and CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_PRIOR_KNOWLEDGE tries only HTTP/2 (with TLS for HTTPS request and without it for HTTP request).